# Input from Amazon connect to Lambda function contains phone number as +1 always; even if I am calling from Germany number

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I am calling AWS Lambda from Amazon Contact Flow, the default input from contact flow to lambda function is sending phone number of the customer with "+1XXXXXXXXXXX". Though, I am calling from Germany number "+49-XXXXXXX".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a defect, you should open a support case to raise the issue to the Amazon Connect service team.